# Did a Green party ever come first in national elections?

Tags: green-party

In [Opinion polls for the Icelandic parliamentary election, 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_parliamentary_election,_2017#Opinion_polls), the [Vinstrihreyfingin – grænt framboð](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-Green_Movement) (*Left-Green Movement*) is leading in most polls, with recent polls giving it 22%–30% with a 0%–8% lead over the number 2 (depending on the specific poll).  There is thus a real chance it may become the largest party in the elections on 28 October.

Has any Green party ever become the largest party in national elections?  I'm aware of the [Baden-Württemberg state election, 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg_state_election,_2016) where the German Green Party came first (with 30.3%), but that's within a single German federal state and thus not on a national level.

Comment: The winner of the [Austrian presidential election, 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austrian_presidential_election,_2016) belongs to the Green party.

Comment: @fedorqui True... but he was running as an independent.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that no, [a Green party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_party) has never been the largest party in a national election, although Green parties have been part of a governing coalition government, together with other larger parties, in some national parliaments on a few occasions.